# Run process under group on solaris

Tags: solaris, group

On linux, in order to run a process under a different group, you can use the `sg` command. For example,

```
sg <groupname> -c 'id -g'
```

prints out the group id of the group name "groupname". Note that `newgrp` can not be used in shell scripts to achieve this.

Is there an equivalent command for solaris? Does the solution also work on my solaris 5.8?

Comment: Can't you just do `echo 'id -g' | newgrp <groupname>` ?

Comment: @meuh Thanks, that worked, indeed! What is the sense of `sg` if one can pipe the command into newgrp already?

Comment: *What is the sense of `sg` if one can pipe the command into newgrp already?*  Indeed.  Especially given that [`newgrp` is standard POSIX.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/newgrp.html)  Nice example here:  http://solaristipsandtricks.blogspot.com/2011/08/solaris-newgrp.html

Comment: @meuh Feel free to write a complete answer, I'll accept it in the next days.